# Ajax Jquery - Acumulando as requisições

Tags: jquery, request

Bom dia a todos,

Estou com um problema bem estranho com um sistema que peguei para dar manutenção. Todos os requests que eu faço para o servidor vem se acumulando.

Por exemplo:
- realizo a exclusao do usuário 01. Ele envia a requisição e exclui o usuario sem problemas.
- realizo a exclusao do usuário 02. Ele envia a requisição de exclusao do usuário 01 e 02, a primeira da erro (pq o usuario nao existe mais)  e exclui o usuario 02 sem problemas.
- realizo a exclusao do usuário 03. Ele envia a requisição de exclusao do usuário 01, 02 e 03, a primeira e segunda dão erros (pq os usuarios nao existem mais)  e exclui o usuario 03 sem problemas.

Alguem ja passou por um problema parecido, é alguma configuração??

Não sou muito experiente em jquery, qualquer dica ja me ajudaria muito.

Segue o codigo que faz a chamada

```
function confirmar(acao, elemento, campo_nome, campo_valor) {
$('.crud_msg').text(acao + " " + elemento + " com " + campo_nome + " igual " + campo_valor);
    $('#confirm_modal').modal('show');
    $('#confirm_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#confirm_modal_nbtn').focus();
    }).on('click', '#confirm_modal_ybtn', function(e) {
        $('#confirm_modal').modal('hide');
        $.ajax({
            url : '/apsig2/crud?action=' + acao + '&elemento=' + elemento + '&campo_nome=' + campo_nome + '&campo_valor=' + campo_valor,
            type : "POST",
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                if (obj.success) {
                    $('#user-table').bootstrapTable('refresh');
                    $('#action_success').modal('show');
                } else {
                    $('#action_failure').modal('show');
                }
                verifySession();
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#action_failure').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Segue o codigo que gera a resposta:

```
private void process(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        this.req = request;
        getElementAndAction();
        jsonResult = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonResultArray = new JSONArray();
        String resultado = "";
        try {
            campoNome = requestGetParameter("campo_nome", req) != null ? requestGetParameter("campo_nome", req) : "";
            campoValor = requestGetParameter("campo_valor", req) != null ? requestGetParameter("campo_valor", req) : "";

            usuarioSoliciante = (Usuario)requestGetAttribute(USUARIO, request);

            switch (action) {
            case GET_TABLE:
                actionGetTable(jsonResultArray);
                resultado = jsonResultArray.toString();
                break;
            case EDITAR:
            case EDIT:
//              actionEdit();
                break;
            case EXCLUIR:
            case DELETAR:
                actionRemove();
                break;
            case REMOVER:
                actionRemove();
                break;
            case INSERT:
            case INSERIR:
            case PERSIST:
            case SAVE:
                actionInsert();
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            jsonResult.put(SUCCESS, false);
            JSONObject errors = new JSONObject();
            errors.put(REASON, e.getMessage());
            jsonResult.put(ERRORS, errors);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(resultado)) {
            resultado = jsonResult.toString();
        }
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(resultado)) {
            JSONObject errors = new JSONObject();
            jsonResult.put(SUCCESS, false);
            errors.put(REASON, "Nenhum resultado ao realizar a pesquisa.");
            jsonResult.put(ERRORS, errors);
        }
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.getWriter().print(resultado);
    }
```

Obrigado

Comment: As requisições são assíncronas usando AJAX, a primeira que você mandou "pode" ser executada por último, mas isso que você comentou é estranho. Consegue compartilhar o código da sua chamada AJAX?

Comment: Então responda a pergunta, por favor. Em seguida designe a sua resposta como correta para fechar a questão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Na verdade a cada vez que o codigo abaixo era executado não era sobrescrito o evento "click" e sim adicionado outro evento "click"

```
 $('#confirm_modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#confirm_modal_nbtn').focus();
    }).on('click', '#confirm_modal_ybtn', function(e) {
        $('#confirm_modal').modal('hide');
...
```

Por isso eles se encadeavam...

Answer (score 0):

O comando `.on('click')` atribui um escutador para o elemento `#confirm_modal_ybtn` a cada vez que a função `confirmar` é chamada. Desta forma, ao clicar no botão uma segunda vez o mesmo escutador permanece no botão e um novo também é atribuído.